How to determine which Process objects may safely be inspected without Win32Exception
I'm playing with System.Diagnostics.Process and wrote a little utility:
    var pp = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Id > 0 && p.MainModule != null).ToList();
    pp.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine($"{p.ProcessName} - PID{p.Id} - {p.MainModule.ModuleName} - {p.MainModule.FileName}"));

This crashed because there are some modules where a lot of properties throw Win32Exception e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=net-8.0

Win32Exception A 32-bit process is trying to access the modules of a
64-bit process.

I don't really want to wrap exception handling around my loop if avoidable, is there a way I can determine based on other properties when the process may safely be inspected?
Is there no way a 32bit process can determine the file-path of a running 64bit process?

if you need file path, use QueryFullProcessImageNameW

You can find the architecture of a process by p/invoking GetProcessInformation with the process's handle and asking for PROCESS_MACHINE_INFORMATION.
